# Neo4J-Enterprise upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

My current installed Neo4J-Enterprise version is 2.2.1

I'm trying to use the neo4j-backup tool to store a backup but according to [this issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/pull/187) - since i'm using `spatial`, I need to upgrade my DB to 2.2.3

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install neo4j-enterprise
```

and it says I currently have the most recent addition - but I think i'm still on 2.2.1 since my `README.txt` file in `/etc/neo4j` didn't change, or the database backup didn't work.

In their [website](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html#explicit-upgrade) they also said the because of store changes, I have to allow the store update of the DB will failed to start, but it started with no errors.

How can I verify which version is installed?

How can I install the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

The current stable version of Neo4j is 2.3.1. An upgrade from 2.2.x requires to have `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `neo4j.properties`.

Unless you're using apt pinning you should get the latest version using

```
apt-get install neo4j-enterprise
```

Please note that upgrading neo4j requires a clean shutdown on the old version.

To check for the currently installed version use

```
dpkg -l neo4j-enterprise
```

Since spatial extension provides a separate index provider you need to make sure to have spatial extension installed on the new version as well - otherwise Neo4j won't start up.

For further diagnostics look into `messages.log` in your graph.db folder.